# Converting 2 DateTime variables in c# mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i'm new to MVC. How do i compare two variables of DateTime? Do I convert both to string then compare them or use == or .Equals()?

Comment: _Never_ compare `DateTime` values with their string representation. Because they might generate different representations in different cultures.

Comment: just convert it into string for example `DT1.ToString(String Format) == DT2.ToString(String Format)`